# Mustache is returning previous data with new

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

Im using [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to return json data in a template, but when im making a $.ajax post with a json responce, mustache is returning previous responce data and the new one. How can i prevent mustache having previous data and return only one responce ?

**Script**

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
         url: 'actions/addpost.php',
         data: {wallid: wallid, postmessage: postmessage, files: files},
         dataType: 'json',
         encode: true
       })
       .done(function (data) {
              var template = $('#template').html();
              Mustache.parse(template);   // optional, speeds up future uses
              var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
              $('#newpost').prepend(rendered);
       });
```

**Template**

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
      <div class="panel panel-white">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <label>UserID: {{ userid }}</label>
              <span class="help-block">{{ date_created }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="well-white well-sm">{{ post_text }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">
             <div id="attachmentlist">
               {{ #attachments }}
                   <p>{{ filename }} ({{ filetype }})</p>
               {{ /attachments }}
             </div>
             <br>
             <div class="comment-textarea">
                <form name="commentform">
                    <div class="comment-box media">
                       <a id="comment-box-a" class="pull-left" href="#">
                          <img class="media-object" src="source/images/nophoto.png" alt="...">
                       </a>
                       <div class="media-body form-group">
                          <textarea id="comment-box-msg" name="postMessage" class="form-control" row="1" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>
                       </div>
                       <button id="comment-box-btn-post" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" aria-hidden="true" type="button">Δημοσίευση</button>
                   </div>
                </form>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </script>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, if you have the same data to feed your template, it's because you send it the same data. Athough, you could use Handlebars.js, it's an upgrade to Mustache.js : http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: you are prepending the new in front of the old, use .html(rendered) instead

Comment: Im making a facebook like posts and when i send a $.ajax request, the wall is been updated with the previous posts. So i post 1, returns 1, I post 2, returns 1 and 2 and etc

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use :

```
$('#newpost').html(rendered);
```

instead of using `.prepend` ? This will add the new HTML before the old one, not replace it.

**EDIT :** After a chat disscution, the problem doesn't seems to come from Mustache, but from a weird multiple PHP call. Mustache looks good here.

Comment: This is replacing the post, not add it at the top of the previous and script is showing the previous for seconds before replacing it.

Comment: I used `append` and `prepend` (its the same thing) Its something about the parsing of the data. Not who i send it back to the div

Comment: I don't think it comes from you template, there is no loop on it.

Comment: The only loop that there is, its for the `attachments`

Comment: Yes, but it would not copy the full HTML twice.

Comment: It shouldnt. That the problem

Comment: So, it must come from you JS code. =) Have you displayed `data` at the beginning of the `done` function, to see if its data is like expected  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56258/discussion-between-elfayer-and-john-priestakos).